# Does Sharepoint not store column data in Office documents as custom properties?

Tags: delphi, sharepoint, ms-word

(I develop in Delphi XE7, edit documents locally in Office 2010 and use SharePoint through a corporate Office365 account.)

I have developed a Delphi program that modifies Word 2010 document properties and even filters and orders them by their properties. The folder where the document was stored is a network folder. The only problem is that this is slow for some colleagues in countries other than the folder location.

I thought that by moving the relevant folder to a Sharepoint server and syncing it with a local folder through OneDrive, I could overcome that issue. Also users could choose between the two interfaces, the Web Browser having access to the Sharepoint server or the Delphi program working on the local folder, changes done in one location being synched by OneDrive with the other location.

I made columns in the Sharepoint library matching the Word properties and initially Sharepoint recognized all properties and made nice lists with them.
The problem is that subsequent changes of the properties are not transferred from one place to another.

If the change is done through the Delphi program in local PC, I have overcome the issue by cheating Sharepoint: instead of simply saving a document, the Delphi program copies and pastes the contents into a new document, where the properties are saved and automatically transferred into Sharepoint columns.

But I have not found a workaround when the change of properties is done through Sharepoint…

Apparently, Sharepoint does not store the column data in the document itself, as custom properties. In fact, after downloading the document it still shows as properties the former values, not the ones showing up in Sharepoint.

Should I give up with my intention of changing properties either locally or through Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the Server properties are actually stored in the Office document itself but in a different location. Physically, each type of properties is stored in different files of those that are compressed in a .docx file: custom properties come in the file "docProps/custom.xml", whereas server properties come in "customXml/item3.xml", being referred to with an "internal name" that fills the spaces between words. But anyhow, as noted in some threads here, programmatically server/SharePoint properties can be modified and retrieved through VBA with the collection ContentTypeProperties.